# Use a Zend function in every controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

I need to be able to use a function (redirect with some parameters) from different controlers of my application.

I need to use $this->_helper->redirector($param1, $param2), and declare it just one time somewhere. Then I'll put this function in others controllers. If one day I modify the function, I don't need to modify it in each controller.

What I'm looking for is an equivalent of Symfony's services I guess.

Thanks for help :) .

Comment: What you’re describing sounds like a [Trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Make a Trait that contains that function, then you can use that Trait in as many controllers as you want.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thanks. There is no Zend tool to do it ?

Comment: Zend / Laminas enables controller plugins. That 's exactly what you 're looking for. Do not use traits.

Answer (score 4):

What you 're asking for is called [controller plugin](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-mvc/plugins/) in Laminas or Zend. You can code your own controller plugin, that you can use in every controller you want.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class YourPlugin extends AbstractPlugin
{
    public function __invoke($param1, $param2) 
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

You have nothing more to do as to mention this plugin in your `module.config.php` file.

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'doSomething' => \Application\Controler\Plugin\YourPlugin::class,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        \Application\Controller\Plugin\YourPlugin::class => \Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory::class,
    ]
]
```

If you want to use some dependencies in your controller plugin, you can write your own factory for your plugin and add that dependencies via injection.

As your new plugin is mentioned in the application config, you can call your plugin in every controller you want.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application\Controller;

class YourController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->doSomething('bla', 'blubb');
    }
}
```

Please do not use traits as a solution for your issue. Laminas / Zends already ships a redirect controller plugin. Perhaps a ready to use solution is already there or you can extend the redirect controller plugin ...